# Spark-1.4.1 Loading issues with file path

Tags: file, path, apache-spark, load

Initially I have installed Apache Spark 1.2 and it works well with loading external files to create an RDD like sc.textFile("home/cloudera/inputs/log.txt").
Later when I installed Apache Spark-1.4.1, I am getting error"Invalid File path "home/cloudera/home/cloudera/inputs/log.txt"when my current working directory is home/cloudera.Can anybody assist in this issue.

With Regards

Gopinathtan K M

Comment: Is it  a hadoop file or local file. If it is a local file then do sc.textFile("file:///home/cloudera/inputs/log.txt)

Comment: @hadoopedAs suggested it works with file:///. Many thanks!